# Есть ли таокй сайт на котором люди могут голосовать за создание какого либо проекта или программы?

Tags: веб-программирование, поиск-программ, веб-сайт

Идея состоит в том чтобы пользователи могли создавать голосования на создание того или иного проекта которого сейчас нет, либо проект существует но он не устраивает кого-то, по причинам тем то, пользователи могли даже составлять требования которые они бы хотели видеть в новых проектах.

А разработчики не ломали головы размышляя о том чего хотят люди. И сразу могли увидеть статистику проекта который востребован.

Comment: github, но там нужно голосовать кодом :)

Comment: На нем уже готовые проекты, а так чтобы простой пользователь мог создать голосование, я не видел.

Comment: Так сделай, делов то..

Comment: Я вот и думаю сделать, а сейчас узнаю нет ли аналогов этого.

Comment: В некотором роде, это биржи фрилансеров - заказчики софта голосуют предложением денег за написание нужного им софта ;-)

Comment: любая краудфаундинговая платформа. Просто публикуете проект приложения и ставите желаемую сумму. Если людям интересно Ваше предложение, то денежку оно соберет очень быстро.

Comment: краудфаундинговая нужен для бизнеса, обычные люди туда не ходят.

Comment: ох, ну тогда ждите.